# Pinned point on surface of 3D-object even with rotations and transforms

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, raycasting

Is it possible to recieve the point of a `RaycastHit` as the point on the surface of the collided object, not as a world-space point?
As in, if the object moves, can I have the point stay true to the surface, no matter the transform, rotation, scaling, etc?

I would like to place a pin/marker on the surface of the object and need the point on the surface, but the user can rotate the object, and the point should stay true to the marker placed.

Comment: I know that the point returned from `RaycastHit` is on the surface, but it doesnt "stick" to the surface after rotations, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maybe use the property that gamObjects have in unity: `GameObject.transform.parent` using this you get the code:

```
GameObject toStickTo; //the GameObject you want it to stay, that you provide
RaycastHit hit; //this is the raycastHit you provide
GameObject point = new GameObject("point"); //initializes new gameObject named 

point.transform.parent = toStickTo.transform; //makes it a child of toStickTo allowing it to move with it
point.transform.position = hit.point - toStickTo.transform.position; //sets the position of the point relative to the toStickTo object
```

Later you can get the position by reading it from the point GameObject.
Hopes this works for you!

Comment: Thank you! As far as i can tell, this would habe worked, but i found out i was complicating things and just changed it so that the camera rotates around the object and now all points stay where they are, because they arent moved ...